# What exactly is this telling me to do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

So, I have just started using unity and C# a few days ago and I have no idea what this error is asking me to do.

[image]

My code is this

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Hello, world!");

}

public float forwardForce = 2000f;
public float sidewaysForce = 500f;

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rigidbody.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKey("d"))
    { rigidbody.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0); }

    if (Input.GetKey("a"))
    { rigidbody.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0); }
```

I have tried fixing this for about an hour now and do not understand it. I have tried putting a "}" everywhere I could think of and removing "{'s" everywhere but I have no idea what to do,

Comment: Fixing your problems with brace placement and indentation would help immensely.  The problem with the expected brace syntax error should then become obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If that is your complete code block, you are missing a closing } for the void FixedUpate() {}.

Also, unless that first } on your first line of the code snippet goes to some other code block you are not showing, then that shouldn't be there.

As to the error itself, "Assets\playerMovement.cs(24,72)", that (24,72) is line number and character number. So if you go to the 24th line in that file, to the 72th character in that line, the compiler is tell you it is expecting to see a '}' there.

Based on your now added code snippet, you are still missing the closing } for the FixedUpdate() method. IE:

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Hello, world!");

}

public float forwardForce = 2000f;
public float sidewaysForce = 500f;

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rigidbody.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKey("d"))
    { rigidbody.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0); }

    if (Input.GetKey("a"))
    { rigidbody.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0); }
}
```